# oracle, retail xstore, how correctly create .mnt file

Tags: oracle

i read documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E62107_01/xoffice/pdf/190/html/user_guide/system_settings1.htm#CHDJFBJB

i need to create .mnt file, but there is no clear documentation(or i can't find her) on what it should be .mnt file.

can you tell what should be .mnt file, or url for documentation or example .mnt file

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on Xstore project any more and changed company but so I don't have access to the documentation.
You need Frameworks and Technologies Guide form https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E62106_01/xpos/index.html  but avaliable only for user logged in and conntected to Xstore product.
Base structure of .mnt file was sth like:
INSERT|23|Jhon|Doe|||
Pipelines '|' mean separate columns, but general mapping was described in Dataloader.xml files. You can investigate them. It should help a bit.